# Bootstrap centre horizontal form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to centre a horizontal form in a hero unit, by setting `text-align:center;` and then `display:block-inline;`

See jsfiddle for a demo http://jsfiddle.net/bVJZ2/

But this hasn't quite worked in that the checkbox and submit button are not correctly aligned any more. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: did ya check my answer , its doin wat you intended to do .

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems that doesn't allow you to center the checkbox.

1. `<div class="controls">` has a `margin-left`. You shouldn't put your checkbox inside a that div.
2. The `input[checkbox]` has a `float: left`. You should remove that float with:

   ```
   .radio input[type="radio"], .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
       float: none;
   }
   ```
3. The checkbox is bad aligned. You should add `vertical-align: top` to the last selector.

To sum up:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
   </label>
   <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.radio input[type="radio"], .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/GW8zk/

Comment: I was attempting to replicate the look before moving it to the middle, as per the horizontal example in the bootstrap documentation: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

So how would one shift those back in to alignment with the input text boxes?

Comment: @penguin I don't understand you.

Comment: I was trying to keep the design looking the same as the horizontal form example in the Bootstrap docs. Playing more with your modifications, I've been able to replicate what they looked like: http://jsfiddle.net/XpbV5/1/

Comment: But what do you use a `form-horizontal` if you only want a normal form?

Comment: I was looking to have the field names to the left of the inputs, like in the examples Bootstrap provide. Unless there's a way to do this via a normal form?

Comment: The jsfiddle is now different, the last one was the normal layout of a bootstrap form, that's why I said that. No, if you want field names to the left `form-horizontal` it's the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Well This is how you can implement a Hero-unit with form centered in middle .

JSFiddle with centered form http://jsfiddle.net/shail/YmmVS/

First the css :

```
.hero-unit {
padding:50px 50px 50px 50px;
    }
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    width: 61px;
    }
.form-horizontal .controls {
margin-left: 80px;
    }
  /* Landscape phones and down */
  @media (max-width: 480px) { 

   .hero-unit{
        margin-left:-20px;
        margin-right:-20px;
      }
   .form-horizontal .controls {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
  }
```

[image: form]
The Html Part :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="hero-unit">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="offset4 span4">
            <legend>Sign in to WebApp</legend>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```